# audiodg.exe is hogging my CPU

Tags: windows-vista, performance, audio, cpu-usage

Every time I play audio on my computer, it starts lagging badly. After checking with the processes, audiodg.exe is being a greedy b**** and hogging my CPU. I've tried ending the process (with regret) and that seemed to give me the 'blue screen of death' where a blue screen with a load of writing shows up and then restarts the whole system.

Any idea on how I can stop audiodg.exe from hogging the CPU?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-disable-windows-7-media-player-network-sharing-service-wmpnetwk/

Although the Audiodog file was running, it was actually the WIndows Media Streaming Network Sharing Service that was hogging the most memory. It all started when I was streaming to audio and video files from a file share through the Media Player.  Right after the Streaming Function kept running.  Found out that it runs by default and was consuming 57% of CPU.  After stopping the process and setting it to manual or disable, it fixed the problem.  See the link at the top. Yeahhhh! My PC is back to normal

Comment: I just diagnosed a customer's laptop that wmpnetwk.exe was using 2.5GB RAM and 100% of one of his CPU cores!!  Causing the laptop fan to run loudly and burn his battery time.

Answer (score 0):

Try by disabling audio effects.

In order to fix the high CPU usage, you should disable the audio enhancements processed by the audiodg.exe file. To disable the audio enhancements, use the following steps:

- Right-click the speaker icon in the lower right corner.
- Select Playback Devices from the menu. A list of devices should
  appear on the screen.
- Double-click the device that has a green checkmark. The properties
  windows for that device should open.
- Click the Enhancements tab at the top.
- From the list of enhancements, uncheck all of them, or click the
  Disable all enhancements checkbox.
- Click the OK button to save your changes and close the window.
- Click OK to close the Playback Devices window.

The ***audiodg.exe*** file hosts the audio engine for Vista. All the DSP and audio processing is performed within this file. Vendors are able to install their own DSP and audio effects into the audio pipeline, which will then be processed by ***audiodg.exe***.
Some audio effects can consume CPU and memory if not properly coded.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've already tried that. Doesn't seem to have any affect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

disable all audio effects that the sound card offers and test again.